# Add dynamic classes to an unordered list with PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, html-lists

I'm trying to add consecutive classes to all list-items in a list with the class of 'nav'.  Essentially, I want every list-item to have a class of 'nthChild-x', where x represents its position in the list.  I'm a major noob to PHP, so be easy.

Here is the current markup:

```
<ul id="primaryNav" class="nav">
    <li>Blah Blah Uno</li>
    <li>Blah Blah Dos</li>
    <li>Blah Blah Tres</li>
</ul>
```

I want this list to be rendered as the following:

```
<ul id="primaryNav" class="nav">
    <li class="nthChild-1">Blah Blah Uno</li>
    <li class="nthChild-3">Blah Blah Dos</li>
    <li class="nthChild-3">Blah Blah Tres</li>
</ul>
```

Please don't reply with a JavaScript or JQuery solution. I know how to do this with JS but need this to be server-side. Also, I don't necessarily want to target the ID of the list because I'd rather do it once and target all lists (though that could be a start).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the markup being generated by PHP in the first place, or are you trying to use PHP to modify existing markup and add classes? If the former, please post the PHP which generates the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DOMDocument for that.

This one will work with existing classes and won't add the same class twice.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$lists = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');

foreach($lists as $list) {
    $index = 1;
    foreach($list->childNodes as $node) {
        if ($node->nodeName != 'li') {
            continue;
        }

        $class = array();

        if ($node->hasAttribute('class')) {
            $class = preg_split('/\s+/', $node->getAttribute('class'));
        }

        $addClass = 'nthChild-' . $index;

        if (in_array($addClass, $class)) {
            continue;
        }

        $class[] = $addClass;

        $node->setAttribute('class', implode(' ', $class));

        $index++;
    }

}

$html = '';

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $element) {
    $html .= $dom->saveXML($element, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/nuvhj4WH).

Comment: This looks more scalable and the path I was on but when I place this code in an external file and call the file in the document. It doesn't change anything.  This is how I'm calling it:
    <?php require_once('file.php'); ?>

Comment: @kevdev You need to pass the HTML source to the file and then output/save or cache the output.

Comment: So, do you mean add a variable like the following?

    $markup = '<ul id="primaryNav" class="nav">
    <li>Blah Blah Uno</li>
    <li>Blah Blah Dos</li>
    <li>Blah Blah Tres</li>
    </ul>';

Comment: @kevdev Yes, you need to pass it to `DOMDocument->loadHTML()` as a string, unless it is a file, and you can use the [`loadHTMLFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't use any template system (like Smarty) to generate this. Than you have to use cycle to generate the fields together with integer variable that will have number of iteration stored. It can be done for example like this:

```
<ul id="primaryNav" class="nav">
    <?php
    $values = array(1 => "Blah Blah Uno", 2 => "Blah Blah Dos", 3 => "Blah Blah Tres");

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        echo "<li class=\"nthChild-" . $i . "\">" . $values[$i] . "</li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

This solution is quite simple, of course there are many better ways how to do this.

Comment: This works but can I do this while keeping the PHP in an external file and targeting every nav?  I don't want to include this in the markup for every unordered list.  Also, the list-items can vary with respect to their inner content (some have 'a' tags inside).

Comment: Well, if you want to use this solution in more places of the code, you can write function that will generate the `<li>`s. Its content will be similar, you will probably just need to use 2 parameters - values array and class name. Than you can call this function as you want and it will always echo/return the list. The base of this function would look somehow like this: function gnerateList($values, $classNAme) { _..._ }

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the list formatted as you've shown here (not in a PHP array), you can do it like this

```
$markup = '<ul id="primaryNav" class="nav">
    <li>Blah Blah Uno</li>
    <li>Blah Blah Dos</li>
    <li>Blah Blah Tres</li>
</ul>';

if (preg_match_all("/<li>(.*)<\/li>/U",$markup,$result) > 0)
{
    $newMarkup = "<ul id=\"primaryNav\" class=\"nav\">\n";
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($result[1] as $listElement)
    {
        $count++;
        $newMarkup .= "\t<li class=\"nThCild-{$count}\">$listElement</li>\n";
    }
    print $newMarkup."</ul>\n";

}
```